# docker-compose nginx returns 404 when path provided

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've set up a dockerfile for my angular frontend that looks as follows.

```
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install && npm run ng build

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm -rf ./*

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/frontend .

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And a docker-compose that has a frontend section that looks as follows.

```
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: frontend/
    ports: 
      - "3000:80"
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/ I see my application just fine.
However, if I go to any path on the URL such as http://localhost:3000/testPath I am presented with a 404 Not Found error message.

I've tried to override the default nginx configuration with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to configure something like this in your nginx config:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

`try_files` tests if the given `$uri` exists, if not it checks `$uri/` and if that doesn't exist it falls back to the index.html and then your Angular application can handle the route.

Comment: Thanks - my mistake was adding it to the wrong config. Once i added it to "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" everything works :)